# share a method of use axios globally standard for nuxtjs?

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

i want use it for all components and pages and my config present :

~/plugins/axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/'
})
```

but with this way , i must `import axios from '~/plugins/axios'` in components and pages 
i want use something choise for like this :

```
this.$axios.post('url',data).then(res=>{
// do something in here 
}).catch({
// do something in here 
})
```

and no need import more axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the official "Axios Module" for Nuxt.js: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module

```
npm install @nuxtjs/axios
```

First, you can set your `baseURL` in the `nuxt.config.js` or in an env variable (see https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options):

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios'
],
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001/' // or, Environment variable API_URL_BROWSER can be used to override browserBaseURL.
}
```

Then in `<page>`.vue, no more import, axios is injected in the `app` var (see https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage):

```
<script>
export default {
 asyncData ({ app }) {
   app.$axios.$get(`/api/users`).then(
      // do something in here 
    );
    //...
  }
}
</script>
```

Finally, you can handle errors globally with a custom plugin (see https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend)

```
$axios.onError(error => {
  // do something in here 
})
```

Comment: how about $post ?

Comment: it works the same way: `app.$axios.$post(`url`, data).then(...)`. see https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/blob/f638dfe23c8351be80ea1d5c02ac4a0caed74511/index.d.ts

Comment: thank you . i just use app.$axios.post() is working thanks so much